# Auto-configure azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I need that when new users open https://shell.azure.com/ the initial configuration does not have to be set. Is this possible?

All IMGs must be in a storage account that I want

How can I do it? Is there a powershell that I can run when a user needs to use cloudshell? Or which are the minimum permissions to give users for only can create their IMG in storage account that I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abd182bb-6d3c-4577-a820-ff2a6bb9ab5f/autoconfigure-azure-cloud-shell?forum=windowsazuremanagement) MSDN thread. Just sharing for the benefit of broader audience.